# Unable to create Virtual Switch - HyperV

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

Trying to use HyperV for the first time.
I have installed the 'feature' and rebooted. Now when I open Hyper-V and try to create a VM I go through the whole process and then it fails on 
"Hyper-V encountered an error while configuring the network on New Virtual Machine"

I tried to create the VSwitch manually in Hyper-V manager but that fails with "An error occurred while trying to retrieve a list of virtual switches, The operation on computer 'DESKTOP' failed: Generic failure"

I have checked my NIC settings and tried to uninstall the Hyper-V protocol, when trying to install it fails on "Could not add the requested feature. The error is: The requested operation was made in the context of a transaction that is no longer active"

I am on Win 10 Education 1709,

Thanks

Comment: During the New Virtual Machine Wizard, at the 'Configure Networking' section I have the drop down menu but the only option I have is 'Not Connected'

Answer (score 1):

To able to create Hyper-V, we can try the following steps:

Step 1: we need to uninstall the third-part VMs if we have, including VirtualBox and any other VMs.

Step 2: reset the network:
Open the command prompt as an administrator;
Type "netsh winsock reset";

Step 3: restart the computer.

Step 4:, Open control panel, locate to control panel->Programs->Turn Windows features on or off->Hyper-V, tick the Hyper-V as below:
[image]

In my environment, we can see "Hyper-V Management Tools" can be ticked by us,  it means the features of this Hyper-V are not fully used if we does not tick it, so we need to tick it. But "Hyper-V Platform" is grayed out and it can not be ticked by us, it means the virtualization function is disabled, so we need to tick it. We can solve it like this:
1.Enter "BIOS" of the computer, enable virtualization function;
2.Find "Security" ,then find virtualization function, change "disabled" to "enabled".

Ensure tick "Hyper-V" including " Hyper-V Platform " and  " Hyper-V Management Tools "

Step 5: try to recreate Hyper-V.

Comment: I have tried this, unfortunately it is still not working. It fails on the same error if I try to create the VM. If I try to create the network in Virtual Switch Manager it fails, "Generic failure".